# Why does NuGet repeatedly attempt to update the same project with the same package during an update-package?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

While updating a specific package for the entire solution, NuGet appears to finish all the work of updating, but then spends considerable time looping back through all the projects in the solution for the same package again and again.  The message issued for each attempt is "No updates available for 'Package' in project 'Project'". It appears to do this as many times as there are projects in the solution.  You can see this in the screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot]

Does anyone know why NuGet does this or how to alter the update strategy or config files to prevent this from happening?